# Best options to integrate my application with the Nike+ features of the iPhone 4G

Tags: iphone, integration, iphone-4, nike

How can I integrate my application with the Nike+ features of the iPhone 4G. I want to access the data captured and send that to my own applications. There seems to be limited information available on this topic. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still hoping someone out there has an answer. This seems to be such a fun thing to develop for, but there is not any documentation I could find.

Comment: I'm wondering the same.  Have you found anything since posting?

Answer (score 1):

I actually created a PHP class that extracts data from the Nike+ service. It might be of use to you. You can find the download and documentation at http://nikeplusphp.org

Not sure how you would save authentication in your app, but this class would definitely give you access to literally everything Nike return back to their own apps and website. Well, everything I could find!

If you do have any issues with the class or anything is missing, please feel free to get in touch or contribute!

Comment: Nike have changed their services a few times, but the Nike+PHP project has tried to keep up and version 4 was recently released.